# Reading a JSON String from Google Maps API

Tags: java, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps api. When I take the following URL and enter it in the browser, I get a pop up window to save a JSON String as a notepad file.

URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bangalore, India&destination=Belgaum, India&sensor=false

... but when I write the following piece of code to programmatically do the same, there is the following exception:

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bangalore, India&destination=Belgaum, India&sensor=false
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
try {
        url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bangalore, India&destination=Belgaum, India&sensor=false");
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            //InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            InputSource geocoderResultInputSource = new    
            InputSource(conn.getInputStream());

              // read result and parse into XML Document
              try {
                geocoderResultDocument =
```

DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Does anyone know what mistake am I doing here?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete blank spaces:

Use:

```
new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bangalore,India&destination=Belgaum,India&sensor=false");
```

Instead of:

```
new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bangalore, India&destination=Belgaum, India&sensor=false");
```

Comment: Thanks Ernesto. That was perfect! Do you know if such calls to Google API is unlimited? I need to make unlimited calls like these.